# Can you make render() method in React Native async?

Tags: react-native, asynchronous

I have a React Native component that needs to fetch an object from Async Storage in order to render. Something like this.

```
class Class1 extends Component {
  async render() {
    let data = AsyncStorage.getItem('data');
    return (
      <View>
        {data}
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

The reason I've made me render() method an async function is so that I can await the return of the AsyncStorage.getItem() method, so that the component won't try to return the  until after the 'data' object has been returned from Async Storage. However, when I use "async render()" I get "Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child".

Any tips?

Answer (score 5):

No need, you want conditional rendering for something like this.

```
_retrieveData = async () => {
  try {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('data');
    if (value !== null) {
      // We have data!!
      return (
          <View>{value}</View>
      );
    }
  } catch (error) {
    // Error retrieving data
  }
};
```

Then in your render function, call it.

```
render() {
  return (
    {this._retrieveData()}
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! But since you're using "let data = ..." instead of "let data = await ...", won't "if(data)" always get called before getItem() returns, and therefore always return false?

Comment: I've just updated it to use the example from [react-native AsyncStorage documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage). I tend you use [react-native-simple-store](https://github.com/jasonmerino/react-native-simple-store) over AsyncStorage as I find it's easier to work with.

Comment: @gkeenley could you post your workaround? I'm trying to do this as well but can't get it working with the above example