# React Native Async Call in Render Function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, promise

This question is similar to some that have already been asked, such as ([Can you make render() method in React Native async?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54539887/can-you-make-render-method-in-react-native-async)), however none of these solutions I have found so far work for me. I am attempting to display a value from storage, however it needs to be obtained asynchronously, so when I am trying to render it returns an unresolved promise.
These functions store and get the data asynchronously:

```
const storeData = async () => {
  try {
    const value= "hello"
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('@storage_Key', value)
  } catch (e) {
  }
}

const getData = async (key:string) => {
  return (<Text>{await AsyncStorage.getItem('@storage_Key')}</Text>)
}
```

...and then in my return I am trying to do this:

```
<Button
  onPress={() => storeData()}
  title="Store"
  color="#841584"/>
 {getData()}
```

Which I want to display a button that saves data (working I think), and then display that data in a text field. However I keep receiving unresolved promise errors. How can I render something alternate until the value is loaded, and display the data without an unresolved promise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use promise instead async/await function, and it is better to use functional components instead of class component.

First, you must use useEffect function for setState after AsyncStorage setItem:

```
const [asyncStorageItemSet, setAsyncStorageItemSet] = React.useState(false);
const [storageKey, setStorageKey] = React.useState('')
React.useEffect(() => {
  AsyncStorage.getItem('@storage_Key').then(res => {
    setStorageKey(res);
})
}, [asyncStorageItemSet])
```

and your return likes this:

```
<Button
  onPress={storeData}
  title="Store"
  color="#841584"/>
<Text>{storageKey}</Text>
```

and storeData function looks like this:

```
const storeData = () => {
  const value= "hello"
  AsyncStorage.setItem('@storage_Key', value).then(res => {
    setAsyncStorageItemSet(true)
})}
```

Answer (score 0):

With functional components, broadly you want to

- use the `useState` hook to create a variable/setter to hold the value you eventually get back from the promise.
- use the `useEffect` hook to run the asynchronous process.

This means you will get at least 2 renders:

1. From before you have a value and
2. When you got the result

The first render the value will *not* be there.

If you haven't used the 2 hooks before, start by learning about them.

Answer (score 0):

No, since the async functions are executed differently, the first instance of an asynchronous function does not return anything, in this way the render will return null which is worth a failure of the rendering of the component, that is maybe why we cannot directly call the Async function inside the render